# Find a basis $\alpha$ of eigenvectors of T and determine $[T]^{\alpha}_{\alpha}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let T: $F^{2}_{2} \rightarrow F^{2}_{2}$ be the linear transformation defined by $$T(x_{1}, x_{2}) = (0,x_{1}+x_{2})$$

Find a basis $\alpha$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$ and determine $[T]^{\alpha}_{\alpha}$.

What I know:

Now, I wish I could say I have a slight idea on how to go about this question but I must admit I'm absolutely stuck. I do know that we must obtain a matrix $[T]^{\alpha}_{\alpha}$ upon which we must perform some calculations $(T - \lambda I)$to obtain our eigenvalues and thus our eigenvectors and use the eigenvalues to then compute our basis $\alpha$ so I'm comfortable about the processes involving **after** getting $[T]^{\alpha}_{\alpha}$. But in order to do that, I must find $[T]^{\alpha}_{\alpha}$ first.

Any advice?

Comment: If you're really stuck, you can always compute another matrix for $T$ that you're comfortable with (maybe the standard matrix?), compute its eigenvalues and eigenvectors, then use them to find the matrix that you need.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, eigenvalues and eigenvectors satisfy
$$T(x_1,x_2)=\lambda(x_1,x_2)$$
with $(x_1,x_2)\ne(0,0)$.  In your case this gives
$$0=\lambda x_1\ ,\quad x_1+x_2=\lambda x_2$$
and by considering the two possibilities $\lambda=0$ and $\lambda\ne0$ I think you will be able to solve this.  Don't forget that $x_1,x_2$ are in $F_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $T((1,1))=(0,0)=0\cdot(1,1)$ and $T((0,1))=1\cdot (0,1)$. This tells us that the matrix representation $[T]_\alpha^\alpha$ with respect to the eigenbasis $\alpha=\{(1,1),(0,1)\}$ is
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$